# Why doesn't ListUsers/GetUser include PasswordLastUsed attribute [AWS/IAM]?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I'm trying to get `PasswordLastUsed` parameted in [list_users (boto3 library)](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.list_users), but response does not include this attribute. The steps are pretty straightforward and I expect to see a `PasswordLastUsed` for one of my IAM users. Am I missing something?

I simply list all users by this command:

```
print(client.list_users())
```

My output:

```
{
   "Users":[
      {
         "Path":"/",
         "UserName":"user1",
         "UserId":"XXXXXXX",
         "Arn":"arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXX:user/user1",
         "CreateDate":datetime.datetime(2018,
         8,
         27,
         15,
         52,
         19,
         "tzinfo=tzlocal())"
      },
      {
         "Path":"/",
         "UserName":"user2",
         "UserId":"XXXXXXX",
         "Arn":"arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXX:user/user2",
         "CreateDate":datetime.datetime(2019,
         9,
         26,
         17,
         43,
         51,
         "tzinfo=tzlocal())"
      }
   ],
   "IsTruncated":false,
   "ResponseMetadata":{
      "RequestId":"xxxxxxx",
      "HTTPStatusCode":200,
      "HTTPHeaders":{
         "x-amzn-requestid":"xxxxxxx",
         "content-type":"text/xml",
         "content-length":"2335",
         "vary":"accept-encoding",
         "date":"Tue, 09 Nov 2021 23:06:45 GMT"
      },
      "RetryAttempts":0
   }
}
```

Expected output based on [the documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.list_users)

```
{
    'Users': [
        {
            'Path': 'string',
            'UserName': 'string',
            'UserId': 'string',
            'Arn': 'string',
            'CreateDate': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
            'PasswordLastUsed': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
            'PermissionsBoundary': {
                'PermissionsBoundaryType': 'PermissionsBoundaryPolicy',
                'PermissionsBoundaryArn': 'string'
            },
            'Tags': [
                {
                    'Key': 'string',
                    'Value': 'string'
                },
            ]
        },
    ],
    'IsTruncated': True|False,
    'Marker': 'string'
}
```

After checking out documentation, I also used [get_user function](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.get_user), but it still does not include `PasswordLastUsed`. According to the doc, *For users that signed in after May 23, 2018 14:08 PDT, the returned password last used date is accurate.* As my user is created after 2019, I assume I should be able to receive this info. Do you have any ideas on this?

The output for `client.get_user(UserName='specificuser')`

```
{
"User":{
    "Path":"/",
    "UserName":"specificuser",
    "UserId":"XXXXXXXXX",
    "Arn":"arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:user/specificuser",
    "CreateDate":datetime.datetime(2019,
    9,
    26,
    17,
    43,
    51,
    "tzinfo=tzlocal())",
    "Tags":[
       {
          "Key":"Name",
          "Value":"specificuser"
       }
    ]
 },
 "ResponseMetadata":{
    "RequestId":"XXXXXXXXX",
    "HTTPStatusCode":200,
    "HTTPHeaders":{
       "x-amzn-requestid":"XXXXXXXXX",
       "content-type":"text/xml",
       "content-length":"581",
       "date":"Tue, 09 Nov 2021 23:21:23 GMT"
    },
    "RetryAttempts":0
 }
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that the user actually use AWS console to login? Not SSO or other type of authentication?

Comment: To follow-up with what Marcin said, what do you see if you look at this user in the AWS Console? What do you see if you generate a credential report for the account?